# How can I respond to an http get request with AppleScript results?

Tags: applescript, http

I have an AppleScript that produces JSON with which I would like to provide in response to an http get request.

[Update]:

I discovered the following on the *MacScripter* website. Question now is how to have the web server (MacOS Server’s Web Service specifically) invoke the AppleScript *Handle CGI Request* Handler with the arguments from the HTTP GET.

> ... In fact, the Standard Additions scripting addition, which is built
>   into Mac OS X, defines several command handlers.
>
> One such handler is handle CGI request, which can be found within the
>   Internet suite in the Standard Additions dictionary. This command
>   handler can be used within a stay opened script application to process
>   CGI (Common Gateway Interface) requests from a web server.

Comment: You may be able to do it in a CGI script using the `osascript` command. Be careful security wise when shelling out like that though